# Search and replace variable

Tags: matlab

I have some 100+ conf files that I am working. I need to find and replace various variable for all these files. For example, I'd like to find the line

Amplitude = 100; and replace it to: Amplitude = 200; for all files.

I've searched in online and found the solution only for one file. I'm looking for a way to do that in Matlab. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If these files can be opened as normal text files then I wouldn't use matlab. Notepad++ has an replace option for as many files as you want, just make sure, you test it out on a backup file first. so have it find "Amplitude = 100" and replace that by what you want.

To see how to do it, look here:
[how-to-find-and-replace-lines-in-multiple-files](https://superuser.com/questions/1003790/how-to-find-and-replace-lines-in-multiple-files-using-notepad)

If you can't do that, put all the files in the same directory (you have to do this anyway). Then load the files in matlab with that directory and run a for loop. However it might be a bit slow./
Basically if you can do 1 file, you could do all of them with a for loop.

If you need help with that I show can some code I used before.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the code that worked in this case?

Comment: Yes but you'll have to adapt it and I'll have to look for it tomorrow morning or so.
Still I suggest using notepad++, you never answered if you could open it with a text editor and get normal text. Downloading it takes a few seconds and you'll be able to do this in like 5 minutes or so, so why rewrite some matlab code which would take about 15 minutes or even much longer depending on your skills.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Linux. Notepad++ is not available for Linux or Mac. That's why I am unable to use it. I am also trying to write a code to run the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Matlab solution would be to (recursively) open all files in the directory. Here I show example for non-recursive solution (it does not check subfolders), though it would be easy enough to modify it to search subfolders too if needed:

```
d = dir(yourPath);
for i = 1 : length(d)
    if ~(d(i).isdir)
       %d(i) is file.
       replaceSingleFile(strcat(d(i).folder, d(i).name));
    end
end
```

As you say, you already know how to do replace for a single file, though to have complete answer here, solution could be along the lines (in the function `replaceSingleFile`).

```
F = fopen(fileYouWantReplaced);
i = 1;
while (~feof(F))
   L = fgetl(F);
   L = strrep(L, 'Amplitude = 100;', 'Amplitude = 200;');
   Buf{i} = L;
   i = i + 1;
end
fclose(F);

%now just write all Buf to the same file again.
F = fopen(file..., 'w'); % Discard contents.
for i = 1 : numel(Buf)
   fprintf(F, '%s\n', Buf{i});
end
fclose(F);
```